# Couldn't load .json and images files in assets folder from angular application

Tags: angular

I send a request to load i18n.json file and some images from 'assets' folder, but just receive 404 not found. Do I need to add any thing to webpack.config.json? If needed, how it is?

**Note: I didn't use Angular-cli so I don't have angular.json for configuring assets from root.**

```
translationsUrl = '/assets/i18n/header';

loadTranslations(locale: string) {
        return this.http.get(`${this.translationsUrl}/${locale}.json`).subscribe((data: any) => {
        });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I created this app from nothing and I didn't use angular-cli

Comment: try using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying it inside angular.json like the below:

```
"assets": [
          ...
          "src/assets/i18n/header/vn.json",
          "src/assets/i18n/header/en.json",
        ]
```

Comment: because I didn't use Angular-cli to create this app, so I don't have angular.json to add those configuration. How I can do now?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load the json like that way because it will not work. you need to set it as promise to load that file. I forgot the reason. but, last year I solved it by this solution.

I wrote one article about it - [Add internationalization (i18n) to an Angular app](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/add-internationalization-i18n-to-an-angular-app-b8fa8b51deea?source=friends_link&sk=ae74bcb34d20e702d701062e9f6417b6)

try:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {

  translateObject: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadTranslations(lang: string = 'en'): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise<{}>((resolve, reject) => {
      const langPath = `assets/i18n/header/${lang}.json`;
      this.http.get(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.translateObject = translation;
          resolve(this.translateObject);
        },
        error => {
          this.translateObject = {};
          resolve(this.translateObject);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Then add one `translate` pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'src/app/shared/services/translate.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
  pure: false
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  transform(key: any): any {
    return this.translate.translateObject[key] || key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have no ideas whether we need ```translate``` pipe?. When I tried with your guideline, I just added the Promise to ```loadTranslations``` and It still doesn't work

Comment: I think u made something wrong. If u follow guideline in the article I think it will run 100% for sure because I applied it many times. Could you share your demo?

Comment: Yeah... Because I didn't use angular-cli to generate my app, so I don't have angular.json file to add this ```  "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],```  Is it the root cause that leads to my issue?

Comment: Yes. I think so. Could you change the path by using dot dot like `../../assets` and try again. If it working, then build again in AOT mode to make sure it is working for production.